# kubernetes Job in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Job:

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to create a migration but it's failing with the below error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "kubernetes/migration-job.yaml": Job in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Job: v1.Job: Spec: v1.JobSpec:
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: You are not citing the whole error message, and the part that you are citing is generic; having read your answer below I can tell you that the _actual_ error message said something along the lines of `ReadString: expects " or n, but found 3` which indicates the reason you stated in your answer.

Comment: No text like that was shown - only the object as JSON. Hence why I posted the question... Probably a bug

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue was to do with one of the yaml fields:

```
env:
  - name: DB_HOST
    value: "mysql"
  - name: DB_PORT
    value: 3306
```

`3306` should be a string (`"3306`") instead...